# drupal 8 pagination is not working for select query

Tags: php, pagination, drupal-8

i have a drupal 8  select query which returns list of items , i want to add pagination to it , but the pager is coming in the node but it is not paging correctly it is showing all the results , here is my code

```
    $sql = "SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type='used_item'";
        $item_nids= \Drupal::database()->query($sql)
                    ->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
        $total=count($item_nids);
       $num_per_page='12';
    
        $pager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager')
          ->createPager($total, $num_per_page);
        $page = $pager
          ->getCurrentPage();
        
       
        // Load the item nodes from the list array.
        $item_nodes = Node::loadMultiple(array_keys($item_nids));
        // Build the items.
        $item_build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')- 
 >viewMultiple($item_nodes, 'carousel_card');
    
        $build[] = [
          '#theme' => 'full_list',
          '#name' => $name,
          '#description' => $description,
          '#item_cards' => $item_build,
        ];
        $build[] = [
          '#type' => 'pager',
        ];
        return $build;
```

please let me know if i am doing anything wrong .

Answer (score 1):

Always look to Drupal core for better examples of how to utilise the API.  Here are two examples which might help;

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!tracker!tracker.pages.inc/function/tracker_page/8.6.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!dblog!src!Controller!DbLogController.php/function/DbLogController::topLogMessages/8.6.x

One of the most glaring things you're missing is that you're not extending the pager so it can't alter your query.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->extend('Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Query\\PagerSelectExtender')
  ->fields('n', ['nid'])
  ->condition('n.type', 'used_item')
  ->id());
```

This is how it applies the "range" for pagination.